# How to pronounce or hyphenate the word 'value'?

Tags: hyphenation

Should it be **val-ue** or **va-lue**?

Is there a rule for this kind of thing?

Comment: If this is a meaningful question at all, it should be addressed at [linguistics.se](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Disagree. I just went through a superpainful process because of my publisher using a Docbook-to-PDF converter written by Japanese who had never heard of the standard Knuth–Liang hyphenation algorithm for English. I had to write a program to iteratively analyse against ᴋʟ and stick things in their exception list. They would split one-syllable words, all kinds of nonsense.   It was horrible. I do think this belongs in ᴇ&ʟᴜ. It is interesting enough the Knuth addressed it. Also, Bringhurst talks about this at length. It varies from one language to the next, even ᴜᴋ v. ᴜs.

Comment: @tchrist: If we're talking pronunciation here then imho this is *way* beyond the scope of ELU. I'm not a linguist by profession, but I studied it to degree level, and if I can't see the distinction I don't know why ELU should be dealing with it - it's lingiustics.se or nothing. If we're talking about typesetting (which I think is your context), it's just out-and-out off-topic.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ok you’re right: I guess we don’t know whether he’s asking for pronunciation or for typesetting. I don’t even know what  “pronunciation” would mean.    But if he can’t ask what proper **English-language** hyphenation **usage** is on **ᴇ&ʟᴜ**, where then *can* he ask it? This is not a linguistics question. In this case, it’s *val–ue* because the *a* is short, and arguably also because you would lose the bound morpheme if you split it. ᴜᴋ *pro–cess* ᴜs *proc-ess*.

Comment: @tchrist: I can't "pronounce" **va-lue** different to **val-ue**, and the concept doesn't make sense to me, but you never know. A **lot** of people take it for granted they can pronounce/hear a difference between **prince** and **prints** if they really want to. But when pressed, most/all of them can't.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Pronunciation is totally on-topic here, well within topic. See the FAQ, 4th bullet point.

Comment: I believe pronunciation to the OP was intended to be his first rule for finding syllables, and thus, his way of determining hyphenation, which exists as part of the practices of writing english text in publications, and should be on topic for English.SE.

Comment: I would strongly advocate that the one and only absolute rule to follow here would be: "Your publisher is always right." Call it pragmatism or call it the only practicable solution. I have gone through the "superpainful".

Comment: There's the Knuth-Liang algorithm for hyphenation which gives 'val-ue'. See [wiki hypenation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphenation_algorithm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relevant rule here is: if there is a reasonable alternative, do not hyphenate a word after a short vowel. So *val-ue*.

The hyphenation rules for English are very complicated, and some of the ones *Merriam-Webster* uses for American English (e.g., *fair-ies* but *prai-ries*) depend on pronunciations which are 100 years out of date. The only reasonable thing to do is to use a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

The direct answer to your question is that it is **val–ue**.

The reasons for how to hyphenate English are really quite complex, and indeed can sometimes vary depending on whether you’re cispondian or transpondian.

And yes, there are rules for these things, more complicated than I can spell out here. The best thing you can do is to consult a hyphenation dictionary, or to run a program than implements Knuth–Liang.

I can probably dig up references for you in a moment.